# Access PDF hyperlinks with pdf.js

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, pdf.js

Im using pdf.js to parse a PDF generated from a Google Doc using Google Scripts. I need to ultimately produce a list of the hyperlinks on a given page of the pdf.

I need an equivalent to the pdf.js function `PDFpage.getTextContent` but which includes hyperlink information, not just text information. Any function within pdf.js that outputs hyperlink information would be a start, but I can't seem to find anything.

I don't need to display the PDF, just extract minimal information from it.

My current code, which just logs the text content of the page:

```
function numbersLinks(blob) {
    PDFJS.getDocument({data: blob}).then(function (PDFdoc) {
      for (var i=1; i<=PDFdoc.numPages; i++) {
        PDFdoc.getPage(i).then(function (PDFpage) {
        var page_number = PDFpage.pageIndex + 1;
          PDFpage.getTextContent().then(function (text) {
            for (var j in text.items) {
              var item = text.items[j]
              console.log(item)
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: pdf hyperlinks are annotations (not a text) -- overlay items on the page, see getAnnotations() instead

Comment: I tried getAnnotations, but it returned an empty array despite there being links on the page. I'll look into it a bit more though, thanks

Comment: getAnnotations() might not work though if annotations are hyperlinks between the PDF pages or there are no actual hyperlinks in PDF (sometimes PDF readers are faking hyperlink by matching http:// or www. patterns)

Answer (score 2):

Is this useful for you?

You can get URLs  using key of `url` from `annotationData` got by `getAnnotations()`.

```
function numbersLinks(blob) {
  PDFJS.getDocument({data: blob}).then(function (PDFdoc) {
    for (var i=1; i<=PDFdoc.numPages; i++) {
      PDFdoc.getPage(i).then(function (PDFpage) {
        PDFpage.getAnnotations().then(function (annotationData) {
          for (var j=0; j<annotationData.length; j++) {
            console.log(annotationData[j].url);
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
}
```